# Make HTML message disappear

Tags: php, html, mysql

Could someone tell me how to make disappear a message after a few seconds?

```
$msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-success">Sikeres rögzítés!</h4>';
```

After receiving the POST, it stays there and I need to reload to make it disappear.

Comment: Use javascript function setTimeout()
https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @TóthLászló - I should also mention, FWIW, that you can optionally inject the javascript (with the `<script>` tags etc,) from the PHP side, in the same string along with the HTML code that you are injecting. Just add it *(PHP-side)* to the string you are echoing. If you add the JS **below** (after) the HTML - even though they are in the same string being echoed into the DOM - you won't need to worry about the elements existing in the DOM before the javascript runs, which is usually something one needs to keep in mind. See the two links below for more info on *that* matter.

Comment: [`addEventListener` vs `onclick` when injecting new elements into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035205/addeventlistener-vs-onclick-with-regards-to-event-delegation) _AND_ [A crash course in how DOM events work](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/a-crash-course-in-how-dom-events-work). Both articles are worth reading, but the second article is very well written and should not be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done client-side (i.e. in javascript) since PHP has finished after echoing the response (and, PHP only works server-side).

Here's a suggested algorithm (pseudo-code):

On the PHP side, add the class `autovanish` (or whatever you want) to the element you want to automatically vanish after so many seconds.

```
$msg = '<h4 class="autovanish col-12 text-center mb-3 text-success">Sikeres rögzítés!</h4>';
```

Then, have a javascript function running all the time:

```
function autovanish(){
   const avDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('autovanish');
   if (avDivs.length){
      setTimeout(() => {
          avDivs[0].remove();
      }, 3000); //removes the element after 3000ms
   }
   setTimeout(() => {autovanish();}, 500); //re-run every 500ms
}
```

In case you are not a js guy, you need the `[0]` after `avDivs` because `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a string.

If you need more assistance than this pseudo-code, ask in the comments.

#### Update:

Further to the code you posted, the top three lines are the part you were missing:

```
<script> 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
       autovanish();
    }

    function autovanish(){
    const avDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('autovanish');
    if (avDivs.length){
       setTimeout(function(){
           avDivs[0].remove();
       }, 3000); //removes the element after 3000ms
    }
    setTimeout(() => {autovanish();}, 500); //re-run every 500ms   
 }
</script>
```

> Thank you for posting the full code - made it easy to see what's what. Two quick changes: (a) first, we need to start (i.e. "call") the autovanish function - otherwise it is just sitting there, but never runs. But before we do that: (b) We add an event listener for the DOMContentLoaded event and put the call to the autovanish function in there. The reason for that is because until all the elements on the page have been created, you might be trying to attach to an element that doesn't yet exist on the page. (In this example (b) is not important but it is a good concept for you to know for the future.) - cssyphus